# 2013 - Setting Object Height to 100% Issues

Tags: 2013, content-editor-web-part

I've been running into some very bizarre issues.  Something that seems (and should be) pretty simple.  What I'm trying to is have objects fill a new page's height 100%.  Initially, I was trying this with a Excel Services Webpart.  I'd create a new blank page, insert the webpart, select the desired spreadsheet from a Document Library, and under appearance, select "No. Adjust height to fit zone."  This spreadsheet only displays, maybe a third of the page.  My suspicion is that its actually the default value of 400px.  When I got back into the webpart options, under Appearance again, the setting returns to assigning as static height of 400px.  As with all of my trials, the width setting works as expected, both at 100% and a specific value.

This made me think that perhaps I needed to edit the master page to increase the size of that zone.  But first I thought I'd try using the Script Editor webpart to put in a different object.  So I tried:

```
<object data="/SalesDocuments/consistency.pdf" type="application/pdf" height="100%" width="100%"  />
```

This again, fills the width as expected, but the height does not.  Again, with the same issue as the spreadsheet, if I assign a height it will work.  I tried burying the object tag inside of a table and a div who also had a height of 100% with no luck.

Has anyone else experienced anything like this?

Answer (score 4):

Note that height 100% means take up 100% of the height of the parent element which may have a static height set and not use the whole page. You can use F12 on IE to bring up the developer toolbar to track down which parent element is limiting the height.

Then create a script and/or CSS style to override the specified height like what was done here [Setting height to 100% in Page Viewer Webpart](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5919/setting-height-to-100-in-page-viewer-webpart)