# SP2010 - Dynamically resize Page Viewer web-part based on content size

Tags: 2010, iframe, page-viewer-web-part

How to change the height and width of a Page Viewer web-part based on the size of the content?

Regards,
Korak

Comment: Did you tried below solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can user below script in ScriptEditor webpart below your Page Viewer WebPart to make show it in full page view.

```
<script language=”javascript”>
var a = MSO_ContentTable.getElementsByTagName(“table”);
MSO_ContentTable.setAttribute(“height”,“100%”);
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
 a[i].setAttribute(“height”,“100%”);
}
var z = document.getElementsByTagName(“div”);
for(i=0;i<z.length;i++)
{
 if(z[i].id.indexOf(“WebPartWPQ”,0) >=0 )
 {
  if(z[i].hasChildNodes())
  {
   if(z[i].firstChild.nodeName.toUpperCase() == “IFRAME”)
   {
     z[i].firstChild.setAttribute(“height”,“100%”);
   }   
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

For further information, Please check below mentioned MSDN article.

[Story of a mischievous Page Viewer Web Part](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/malag/2008/09/15/story-of-a-mischievous-page-viewer-web-part/)

If you want to set only height to 100% thank kindly check below link

[Setting height to 100% in Page Viewer Webpart](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5919/setting-height-to-100-in-page-viewer-webpart)

Comment: Did you tried above code? Is that works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a library that can help you: https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

In this package there are two JS-files, one for the host (SharePoint) and one for the page that you want to show in the iframe. Once both scripts are implemented they will start to negotiate a size for the iframe so that all the content fits inside.